# oracle check regexp_like

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle-xe

hy,

I am trying to put a constraint with REGEXP_LIKE in oracle, but i keep geting a ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

error, here is my code (the error is at the end of the ck_files_name constraint

```
CREATE TABLE files(
  idFile INT PRIMARY KEY,
  idParent INT REFERENCES files,
  name VARCHAR2(256),
  type CHAR(1),

  CONSTRAINT ck_files_name  CHECK REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[^\.]'),    -- error ORA-00920:    invalid relational operator
  CONSTRAINT ck_files_type  CHECK type IN ('d', 'f'),
  CONSTRAINT ck_files_idFile_idParent CHECK (idFile <> idParent),
  CONSTRAINT uq_files_idFile_name UNIQUE (idParent, name)
);
```

Am I doing something wrong, or does it have to do with my oracle version (oracle 10g xe) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to put parantheses after the `check` keyword.

The following works, at least with Oracle 11, R2.

```
CREATE TABLE files(
  idFile INT PRIMARY KEY,
  idParent INT REFERENCES files,
  name VARCHAR2(256),
  type CHAR(1),
  CONSTRAINT ck_files_name  CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[^\.]')),
  CONSTRAINT ck_files_type  CHECK (type IN ('d', 'f')),
  CONSTRAINT ck_files_idFile_idParent CHECK (idFile <> idParent),
  CONSTRAINT uq_files_idFile_name UNIQUE (idParent, name)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Paranthesis is missing.
Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE files(
  idFile INT PRIMARY KEY,
  idParent INT REFERENCES files,
  name VARCHAR2(256),
  type CHAR(1),

  CONSTRAINT ck_files_name  (CHECK REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[^\.]')),    
  CONSTRAINT ck_files_type  (CHECK type IN ('d', 'f')),
  CONSTRAINT ck_files_idFile_idParent (CHECK (idFile <> idParent)),
  CONSTRAINT uq_files_idFile_name UNIQUE (idParent, name)
);
```